# Styling WPF slider background

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider

I'm trying to apply a specific style to a slider control and I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to do for the slider's background.  What do I need to do to get something like this triangle to show in the background of my slider?

I initially thought I would define a GeometryDrawing and set something in the tickbar tag to it - but I can't find anything suitable.

This is what I'm looking for.  Thanks for any ideas.

[Slider background http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/690/slider.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/690/slider.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to investigate a bit more into styling and templatiting in wpf.  I would expect the easiest way would be to define a Control Template but you 'might' be able to achieve this with just styling

Check out this [page on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) for starters. There is probably loads of other resources out there.  Big sections on it in the book i'm reading at the moment - [pro wpf in c# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599551)

Sorry i'm not coming up with an example... you'd be better off doing a bit of background reading and then coming back with any specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [Intuipic](http://intuipic.codeplex.com/) project, which does something similar (only horizontally):

[image]